# Shell Script - opening files from a different directory

Tags: shell, path, cd

I am trying to cd to a different directory by using a path to open a file, but it fails to load correctly.

I am in the directory of ~/Dev/.../Examples to run a ./test.sh script.

Inside the shell script, I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash 
path = '~/Datasets/foo'

....
"path"/bar
```

The Dataset folder is right after cd ~/

I have tried $HOME instead of ~, but it still fails to load the respective file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code to open the bar directory with nautilus (ubuntu's explorer):

```
#!/bin/bash

path='/home/your_user_name/foo'
nautilus $path/bar/
```

Rules:

1. Use absolute path: `/home/your_user_name/`, not `~/` nor `$HOME`.
2. Bash doesn't like spaces: `path='~/Datasets/foo'`, and not `path = '~/Datasets/foo'`

Comment: Thank you very much, setting the absolute path was the issue